# google play service stop working when run app

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am developing wear/handeheld app. I have problem when I run app on handheld, i am getting error "Google play service stopped working".
Stack trace of error is following:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED flg=0x4000010 (has extras)
dat=package:com.fzv.myapp } in com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.u@41d42a08
```

Any ideas what is going on here, because i am working on this problem for 3 days and still not resolved it ...

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: here it is : http://imgur.com/SZ5ICTk,lJbZnFB#0 and http://imgur.com/SZ5ICTk,lJbZnFB#1